# Display the users name

Tags: c#, list, loops, foreach-loop-container

I am trying to let all the names and the contacts display after the user chooses `No`, but the last name keeps displaying, please help.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string choice = "Yes";
    string name;
    string Contact;
 
    List<string> No_B = new List<string>();
    List<string> No_A = new List<string>();
    
    try
    {
        while (choice == "Yes" || choice == "yes")
        {
            Console.WriteLine(" name:");
            name = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("contacts:");
            Contact = Console.ReadLine();
            No_A.Add(name);
            No_B.Add(Contact);
            Console.WriteLine("Do you want to add another contact");
            choice = Console.ReadLine();
            if (choice == "No" || choice == "no")
            {
                foreach (var item in name )
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(item);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (System.Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: There's really only one lines of code to look at to work out the issue: `foreach (var item in name )` `name` is a string variable, you aren't even referencing anything else in this loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string choice = "Yes";
        string name;
        string Contact;

        List<string> No_B = new List<string>();
        List<string> No_A = new List<string>();

        try
        {
            while (choice == "Yes" || choice == "yes")
            {
                Console.WriteLine(" name:");
                name = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("contacts:");
                Contact = Console.ReadLine();


                No_A.Add(name);
                No_B.Add(Contact);
                Console.WriteLine("Do you want to add another contact");
                choice = Console.ReadLine();
                if (choice == "No" || choice == "no")
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < No_A.Count; i++)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"Name: {No_A[i]}");
                        Console.WriteLine($"Contact: {No_B[i]}");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (System.Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Your algorithm only supports adding one contact to a name. If you intent to add multiple contact to a name, additional changes will have to be made to the code.

Here is a slight variation of above code that lets you add multiple contacts to a single name. I have introduced StringBuilder class. This new code has also made List No_A = new List(); unnecessary. **There is always a better algorithm that can be implemented but since you are new I am only suggesting minor changes that will serve your purpose and that will be easy for you to understand.**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string choice = "Yes";
        string name;
        string Contact;

        List<string> No_B = new List<string>();
        List<string> No_A = new List<string>();

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        try
        {
            while (choice == "Yes" || choice == "yes")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter Name:");
                name = Console.ReadLine();
                No_A.Add(name);

                Console.WriteLine("Enter Contact:");
                Contact = Console.ReadLine();
                No_B = new List<string>();
                No_B.Add(Contact);

                while (true)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Do you want to add another contact?");
                    choice = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
                    if (choice == "yes")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Enter Contact:");
                        Contact = Console.ReadLine();
                        No_B.Add(Contact);
                    }
                    else if (choice == "no")
                    {
                        sb.Append($"\nName: {name}");
                        sb.Append($"\nContacts(In separate line):");
                        foreach (string str in No_B)
                        {
                            sb.Append("\n"+str);
                        }

                        break;
                    }
                }

                Console.WriteLine("Do you want to add another name and contact set?");
                choice = Console.ReadLine();
            }

            Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
        }
        catch (System.Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Code correction for the loop**

You can try this:

```
foreach (var contact in No_A)
{
  Console.WriteLine(contact);
}
```

But using two "parallel" lists is *not clean*: it is a code smell and an anti-pattern.

**Using an entity class**

A better way is to create an entity class like:

```
public class Person
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string Contact { get; set; }
  public Person(string name, string contact)
  {
    Name = name;
    Contact = contact;
  }
}
```

That you will use like that:

```
List<Person> persons = new List<Person>();
try
{
  while ( true )
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Name:");
    string name = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Contact:");
    string contact = Console.ReadLine();
    persons.Add(new Person(name, contact));
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Do you want to add another person?");
    string choice = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine();
    if ( choice.ToLower() == "no" ) break;
  }
  foreach ( var item in persons )
  {
    Console.WriteLine($"Name: {item.Name}, Contact: {item.Contact}");
  }
}
catch ( Exception ex )
{
  Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

I don't generally recommend using an infinite loop, but in this case it's an easy way to control the process that ends after entering "no" and any other entry will continue the loop.

Displaying the list of persons entered if done after the loop.